# Android : how to enable crash reporting and diagnostics

Tags: android, crash-reports

A friend has downloaded my app but, while it works on my phone, he keeps getting a message saying "xxx keeps stopping." He presses the send feedback button and gets a message thanking him, but nothing appears on my crash reporting on my play dashboard under Android Vitals.

I'm confused by this, as I've always seen a "report" button rather than "send feedback" when an app misbehaves. And whenever one of the apps on my phone crashes, it always says something like "Unfortunately, xxxx has stopped." I've never seen "keeps stopping" which makes me wonder what it is my friend is seeing.

This makes me thing that he doesn't have automatic crash reporting crash reporting and diagnostics enabled; if he did I could at least get a stack trace. How does one do this? And does anyone have any comments on this? Sorry this is so vague, I just don't know what to make of it.

Comment: Someone asked this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application

Comment: Yes, I read that but it seemed to rely mostly on third party apps etc. I just wanted to know if there a simply switch in "settings" that my friend could activate.