# Silent crash on requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)

Tags: android, crash, android-camera, android-permissions, android-camerax

I have noticed my app crashes on the first install. Further investigation shows this line of code causes it:

```
requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
```

There is nothing in logs which gives a clue on what is going on. App enter into main Activity, navigates into this Fragment and executes sequentially:

```
[onCreateView()] ScannerFragment
[onViewCreated()] ScannerFragment
[onDestroy()] ScannerFragment
```

On the next launch after installation it is launched correctly. More deep dive into [logcat filters](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat) didn't help either.

I few minutes ago I integrated `sentry.io` crash reporter in hope to catch something I might miss, but I haven't received yet an error.

I am posting this issue here in hope someone might faced with such behavior as well.

Thanks!

([here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601503/how-do-i-obtain-crash-data-from-my-android-application) the most extensive overview on what is going on with crash reporting solutions on Android)

Reproduced on Samsung A22 (API 33), but works fine on emulator Pixel 3A (API 34)